# Monkey typing on 29 letter keyboard.

Tags: probability, combinatorics

This monkey is driving me a little crazy. I think he should get fired - it's not nice.

Here is the information. 
A monkey is typing on a 29 letter keyboard. He is writing a word that is 5 letters long.

- How many words can the monkey write? 29*29*29*29*29
- What is the probability the monkey starts with the letter H? 1/29
- What is the probability the monkey writes the word "YASOV"?
  1/29*29*29*29*29
- What is the probability the word contains "H" once?

I don't understand the last one. My best bet would have been 29*29*29*29*1/29^5.
The mindset being that you can press every key (4 times), and then press H once.

Or maybe even 29*29*29*29*29-29*29*29*29*28.

Doing a baby calculation with a keyboard of ABC, and the monkey typing a word of two letters, containing the word "A" only once I get 4/9. I just scribbled every possibility and found the answer, so I assume: 2*2/3*3. I don't see the connection to the 5 in the answer.

I also don't understand why 28 (or 2 for that matter), as 28 would mean 28 possibilities. Wouldn't that be the possibility of not getting H? Every possibility except H?

The correct solution to the real answer is 28^4*5/29^5.

Comment: What you calculated is the probability that his word looks like $\_\ \_\ \_\ \_\  H$, where the blanks could still include H's, when they shouldn't (and also that the H is in one specific spot).

Comment: Oh, so I just times it with 5. Ok, Edit so its not just times with 5

Comment: Ah, I get it. So it's 28*28*28*28*1, because every possibility except H. Times 5

Comment: There we go! Now type yourself up an answer when you get some time :)

Comment: Thanks. Quick and helpful  :P My answer isn't going to be as great as others still though, but ok.

Comment: @pjs36 Hi, I just wonder how many questions I can ask a day? Because this is my third, but I always try to put in a lot effort before I ask. Also, I can't accept my lackluster answer :P

Comment: Just curious, what are the last three letters of the keyboard?

Comment: æ,ø,å from the Norwegian Alphabet.

Comment: @pjs36 please do not tell people to write answers to their questions that already have answers. Answering your own question is only allowed when you are making a Q&A post. Otherwise it violates site customs, and risks deletion.

Comment: @TheGreatDuck Check the timestamps by hovering your cursor over the "answered X hours ago" or "answered yesterday" on the answers. You will see that the OP answered nearly 20 minutes before the second answer was posted. You can tell *me* about "site customs" all you like, but I hope you will reconsider your comment on their perfectly acceptable answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

"What is the probability the word contains "H" once?"

This is slightly ambiguous.  Do you mean the word i) contains at least one H or ii) contains exactly one H?

i) has a trick.  There are are $29^5$ total words.  There are $28^5$ words that contain no H's whatsoever (-- each letter can be any one of the remaining 28 letters).  So there are $29^5 - 28^5$ words that have one or more Hs.

ii) there is a naive way and a sophisticated way.  First the naive way: There are $1*28*28*28*28$ ways to type a five letter word a five letter word starting with H and the rest of the letters are not H.  There are $28*1*28*28*28$ ways to type a word where the 2nd letter is H but the rest are not H.  There are $28*28*1*28*28$ where the third letter is H and so on.

So in total there are $1*28*28*28*28 + 28*1*28*28*28 + ..... + 28*28*28*28*1 = 5*28^4$.

... or the sophisticated way:  The number of ways to type a 5-letter word where a specific letter slot must be H and the remaining 4 letter slots must not be H is $1$ for the dedicated letter slot and $28^4$ for the remaining 4 letters slot (each of which can be any of the 28 remaining letters remaining).  That is $28^4$ possible ways.  Now there are 5 possible choices for which dedicated letter slot is the H.  That means there are $5*28^4$ possible words.  (5 choices for which letter is the H-- and 28 choices for each of the remaining four letters.  Multiply the choices... $5*28^4$.

====

" 2*2/3*3. I don't see the connection to the 5 in the answer"

If you need to figure out $n$ letter word with $m$ choices of letters the number of words with exactly one ~ is $n*(m-1)^{n-1}$.  So the answer with 3 letters and a 3 letter word is $3*(2)^{2} = 12$  [ABB,ABC, ACB,ACC, BAB,BAC, CAB,CAC, BBA,BCA,CBA,CCA].

One 2 corresponds the 28.  The other to the 4.  The 3 corresponds to the 5.

====

Two post-scripts.

I just realized I gave the answers to "What is the NUMBER OF WAYS" rather than "What is the probability".

Well,  Probability of Event = (Number of Ways Event can Happen)/(Number of total things that can happen).

So for i)  Number of ways to get at least one H = $29^5 - 28^5$.  Number of total things that can happen = $29^5$.

So probability is $(29^5 - 28^5)/29^5 = 1 - (28/29)^5$.

for ii) Number of ways to get exactly one H = $5*28^4$.  Number of total things that can happen = $29^5$ so probability is $5*28^4/29^5$.

For your 3 letters and a three letter word: Number of ways to get exactly one A = $3*2^2 = 12$.  Total ways to type three letters = $3^3 = 27$.

So probability = $3*2^2/3^3 = 2^2/3^2$.  Note: because you had 3 letters total and 3 letter length words one of the 3s cancelled.  Which is probably why you didn't see the corespondence.

If you had say a *four* letter word of ABC with exactly one A then the total ways would be $4*2^3/3^4$.  (Do you see why) and no canceling.  That you chose the same number of letters and length of words was a misleading coincidence.

2nd postcript as per aarons comment.... well, I have to go cook dinner now.  I'll get to it later but... It's to introduce the idea of choicing m out of n options.  i.e. how to choice which position the one H is.  Or if you had to calculate the probability of a five letter word with exactly *TWO* Hs--- how to choice which of the 5 positions we can place the 2 Hs....

Think about it.  I'll get back to it.

Comment: It is slightly instructive to write the answer in a way that generalizes, $\binom{5}{1}1^1(29-1)^{5-1}$.

Comment: Good point.  I'll add that as a post note.  I have to add something about probability rather than just total numbers anyway.

Comment: Wow. *jaw drop* This must be the biggest answer I have seen on this site yet. I'll read it tomorrow :) 10 hours of probability is enough for today :P Thanks.

Comment: Well... it just growed... I sometime have a tendency to do that.

Answer (score 1):

_ _ _ _ H We want every possibility except H, in the 4 open spots. That's 
28*28*28*28. In the end we want to be sure we get an H. So it's a 1.

The overall will become 28*28*28*28*1 for the sequence above.

Because they are asking for one H anywhere in the word, we can times this by 5.

Comment: There is no reason to remove 'duplicate' answers, especially not if they were posted first. Indeed, having redundant yet independent answers is desirable. (What is discouraged is to post completely redundant answers a lot later then existing ones.) @TheGreatDuck please do not continue to make such recommendations. [Added: I hadn't seen the exchange on OP else I might not have written this in addition.]

Comment: @TheGreatDuck On the answer, it's no worse than a somewhat typical answer on this site. On the rest, take this up with the person that commented. Still better ask on meta about the subject; I do not intend to continue this discussion in this comment section.